# No access to the web

Tags: website

I answered a phone call a few months back from a guy who said there was something wrong with my computer.

The computer had been acting slow of late so I listened and did what he said. I don't remember what keys he said to type in or even where I was going on the computer. But after that phone call my computer was'nt working right at all.

The most important part is that I cannot get on any websites. I get a message that my virus software is blocking it and I should enable...blah blah...

I did what it said and still the same message. I wound up uninstalling my Norton (after running it for a virus check) software, restarted etc. Still the same message. This is one problem. Another...clicking on any icon I have software installed for does not bring up the program. My pointer is now a capital "I" with a line on the top and bottom of it. Just like when you are typing into a letter etc.

I was thinking of just re-formatting the computer. I have Windows Vista. I don't want to install any of the new Windows formats as I don't want to learn all over again. What do you think that guy that called did to mess me up like this.

I did go into DOS as he was instructing. That's all I remember. I am a senior citizen & rely on my computer for health reasons i.e. checking in with my doctor. Thank you for any advice you can give me.
Regards, Pat

Comment: You you have anyone that can help you?  If you don't know the guy, your machine is probably under his control, and up to no good.  Unless you can find someone you trust to diagnose what they did, then formatting and starting over might be your best option.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. No I do not have anyone here to help me. But, I am not a newbie with computers. My first was WIN95. I even did a newsletter way back then as I was getting inundated with phone calls from family...how do I do this, that etc. I think this medication I take is giving me brain fog!  I will reformat. It'll be like a new computer! Now to search eBay to find a Vista disc! Any ideas on that? Thanks again

Comment: Hi sir, I will send you a legitimate copy of Windows 7 Professional 64-bit if you are in dire need of an OS. Again, it's 64-bit, so, you need to have a 64-bit processor. Here's an e-mail you can send your address to; it's a general contact e-mail from a website that I am designing: contact@simply-a-christian.com. Up to you, but I'd be glad to help you out. In the future, never let anyone do something to your computer unless you know what they are doing. I don't know about you, but many people have very sensitive data on their PC that can cause them a world of hurt if it falls into wrong hands.

Comment: I will gladly accept your offer of the Windows 7 disc. Yes I have 64 bit processor. I will send the email. Thanks so much! Pat (female)

Comment: Sorry I am so late to answer your offer. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sir, have been had.

My recommendation to you, to prevent infection to any devices on your network:

Power down your system.

**Using another machine** download a copy of [Ubuntu Live](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop), and install it to a USB drive using [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Boot your **infected machine** into Ubuntu from the live USB, and use this to backup any files on your system.

After you have saved any files, use the CD's that came with your machine, or download a copy of windows for which you have a CD key, and do a clean install, completely wiping the HDD.

Comment: Thank you. I am using my phone to contact you. Can you please email me these directions so that I can print it out? I really appreviate your help. Email... pspatches@aol.com

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have been scammed.  (A different variant on a theme common here - someone calls up claiming to be from Microsoft and that your computer has issues, then charging you to "clean up" you computer while actually making things worse).

I'd suggest backing up all your documents, reformatting and reinstalling from scratch. Also, be very careful when opening your documents once you recover them - they are probably OK, but might not be.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't pay out any money so that was good. He didn`t ask for payment either. I don`t have anything important there so I don`t have to worry about backing it up. Just came to me...I am able to log in to AOL without a problem.

Comment: I would stop using your computer ASAP until you get it re-formatted.